# Yesod Haskell - How to create PDF reports, with a header and footer on each page?

Tags: haskell, pdf, report, web-deployment, yesod

I am currently trying out `Yesod.Content.PDF` with the function html2PDF, but I also need a way to make a footer and header for each page of my reports. Is there a way of doing this or a better tool for the Yesod ecosystem? I was thinking about using Jasper Reports, but it would require more installations and dealing with other language (Java), I would like to avoid that overhead and keep things as small and simple as possible.

Comment: You can use CSS styles to set header and footer information.

Comment: @BobDalgleish could you make an example?

Comment: I just did a search for "html2pdf header and footer" and came up with lots of examples.

Comment: @BobDalgleish no example has solved my issue, have you already done it?!\

Comment: Are you able to get any results at all from your CSS? One issue I found on another project is that some of the CSS is sensitive to the media type.

Comment: @BobDalgleish no man, I didn't. My deadline to deliver the project were close so I used Jasper Reports

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS pretty easily:

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 36px;
  left: 51px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: We use puppeteer at work, whereas your library uses wkhtmltopdf, but it works on every page for us at least.

Comment: that is the problem, using the wkhtmltopdf alone, I didn't manage to make it out even using the way its documentation tells it should be. Very poor library interface.

Comment: Try with puppeteer (install http://npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cli). It uses headless Chrome, so it's just the same as doing File > Print from Chrome. It's more reliable than other ways because you have a full browser engine at your disposal.